# How do I use user_helper method globally throughout the app views?

Tags: railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I finished [chapter 8](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#top) on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, so I have the app set up to sign users up & sign in and out.

What I am trying to do user a User Helper method inside the application.html.erb (or more specifically inside a _header.html.erb partial).

I want to use the gravatar_for method (Defined in the user_helper.rb) to show the user's gravatar picture and users name instead of having the word "Account" with the drop down.

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 150})
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "http://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

On the show.html.erb page I have the following code

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name ) %>
<div class="row">
 <aside class="span6">
    <section>
        <h1>
          <%= gravatar_for @user %>
          <%= @user.name %>
        </h1>
    </section>
 </aside>
</div>
```

And that shows the user's gravatar and name on their profile page. So what I tried to do was add those same methods to the *header partial* like so;

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span id="small">
        <%= gravatar_for @user %><%= @user.name %><b class="caret"></b>
      </span>
</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li id="cta"><%= link_to "+ Sign up",  signup_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

And that code shows up completely fine on the *show.html.erb* page, which I am assuming is because its the *show action* on the *Users controller*. But when I try to click to the home page or really any other page outside of the *Users View* then I get the error

```
NoMethodError in Pages#about
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

So I guess my question is how do I make the *gravatar for* method and the *@user.name* available to **all** the views throughout the application. I feel as if the answer should be fairly simple, but i'm pretty new to rails, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put the method in the ApplicationHelper instead of the UserHelper. Here is an example of something similar I did in my own app: https://github.com/NatashaTheRobot/tinysale/blob/master/app/helpers/application_helper.rb